# What should I do to add current location in a google map using react native expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

The following APIs have moved to separate packages and importing them from 'expo' package is no longer supported.Permissions

This is the error I am getting while implementing the Google map. And the following screen is like this :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvPGe.jpg)

I am using this code as it is. (https://snack.expo.io/@professorxii/expo-map-and-location-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code that you shared is deprecated by Expo:.
Use this code instead:.

```js
import React from "react";
import MapView from "react-native-maps";
import { StyleSheet, View, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import * as Location from "expo-location";
import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";
import Constants from "expo-constants";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    mapRegion: null,
    hasLocationPermissions: false,
    locationResult: null,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getLocationAsync();
  }

  handleMapRegionChange = (mapRegion) => {
    this.setState({ mapRegion });
  };

  async getLocationAsync() {
    // permissions returns only for location permissions on iOS and under certain conditions, see Permissions.LOCATION
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
    if (status === "granted") {
      this.setState({ hasLocationPermissions: true });
      //  let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({ enableHighAccuracy: true });
      const location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      this.setState({ locationResult: JSON.stringify(location) });
      // Center the map on the location we just fetched.
      this.setState({
        mapRegion: {
          latitude: location.coords.latitude,
          longitude: location.coords.longitude,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        },
      });
    } else {
      alert("Location permission not granted");
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          style={styles.mapStyle}
          region={this.state.mapRegion}
          onRegionChange={this.handleMapRegionChange}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  mapStyle: {
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
    height: Dimensions.get("window").height,
  },
});
```

To learn more here are the links:.
[Expo MapView](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/)
[Expo Permissions](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/permissions/)
[Expo Location](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/location/)